# Can I have svn automatically propset a file after adding it?

Tags: svn

Is it possible to configure svn such that it automatically sets the `svn:keywords` property after svn-adding a file?

That is, when I add a file to svn, I usually do that with two steps:

```
svn add someNewFile.foo
svn propset svn:keywords "HeadURL Revision Author Date Id" someNewFile.foo
```

and I'd like to have the 2nd step automatically done for me by svn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the `svn:auto-props` feature. Details can be found [here](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#auto-props) and [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto).
Note, however, that this is a *client-side feature*, i.e. it is *not done by the server*, but by every client. This means, every client has to change its configuration. This downside is also explained in the provided links.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the client configuration of your svn client.

```
 /home/user/.subversion/config
```

There you find a section with auto-props. That's the area where you can configure that behaviour but ths will work only for added files as you mentioned.